# How to extend file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a project in which I want to extend a file in my Child-Theme.

I have extend using some folders but none of them is helping.

My file which i want to extend is

```
 var/www/html/bmrfactoryshop/app/code/MGS/Landing/view/frontend/templates/category/landing/grid.phtml
```

I want to extend it in my child-theme

Comment: This will help you as you need to create files in `app/design/vendor/themename` too. https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-create-child-theme-in-magento2/

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Thanks for the help i have solved it..

Comment: @Urocks Could you add an answer with how you resolved the issue and accept it? This way it will complete the lifecyle of this question and potentially will help someone in the future.